# Cannot show select all in custom checkbox kendo-grid-checkbox-column

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm work with **angular** and **kendo**, I have a problem to show select all in column header.
Here is my code:

*app.component.html*

```html
...
<kendo-grid 
    scrollable="virtual"
    [height]=500
    [data]="data"
>
    <kendo-grid-column field="" title="No">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-rowIndex="rowIndex"><p>{{ rowIndex + 1 }}</p></ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-column>
    <kendo-grid-column field="item" title="{{ 'COMMON.LABEL.FUNCTION_AUTHORITY' | translate }}">
    <kendo-grid-checkbox-column field="" title="Check all" showSelectAll="true">
        <ng-template kendoGridCellTemplate let-dataItem>
            <input type="checkbox" kendoCheckBox [ngModel]="dataItem.check" />
        </ng-template>
    </kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
</kendo-grid>
...
```

*app.component.ts*

```js
import { data} from './data';
...
data: any[] = data;
...
```

*data.ts*

```js
export const data = [
    {name: "item1", check: true},
    {name: "item2", check: false},
    {name: "item3", check: false},
    {name: "item4", check: true},
    {name: "item5", check: true}
];
```

I do this code in my project but it not show select all in column header.
Please help me, and sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2):

Now I found answer on my question just need to remove **kendoGridCellTemplate**,
so my code

```html
<kendo-grid-checkbox-column field="" title="Check all" showSelectAll="true">
    <ng-template let-dataItem>
        <input type="checkbox" kendoCheckBox [ngModel]="dataItem.check" />
    </ng-template>
</kendo-grid-checkbox-column>
```

it work